# Return only the values of a Concatenate Formula

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I looking to have the concatenate function to return only the values, so that the return may be used for an ImportXML.

I have column A displaying URLs: (https://example.com/admin/v3/suggestions/19658686/)

Column B pulls data from the URL in Column A: (/19658686/)

Column C displays a concatenated version of text + Column B to create a new URL (via formula): (https://example.com/forums/suggestions/19658686/)

Column B: `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("s/",A1))`
Column C: `=CONCATENATE("https://example.com/forums/suggestions",B1)`

I want to use ImportXML to do a lookup using the URL in Column C, but since it is technically a formula it won't work.

I am certainly interested to see if there is a workaround, or even a more efficient method to do this via script. Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let be B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(RIGHT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-SEARCH("s/", A1:A))))
```

and C1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), "https://example.com/forums/suggestions"&B1:B, ))
```

where D1:

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML(C1, "//*"))
```

and drag down...

[image: 0]

Comment: almost works. Column C is returning the same link everytime

Comment: @GVJenn fixed, try now